# Cant type in CLI

Tags: raspbian, hardware, wireless, keyboard, terminal

I've just got a Raspberry Pi 1 B. I installed Raspbian, I've worked with it for full day and everything was working as it should be. I used to booted into the desktop, now I have changed that to boot into the CLI.

After booting it auto-login, I can't write anything, when I click the right arrow I go to tty2 to the login screen and if I type <kbd>a</kbd> I get `^[a` or if I type <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> I get `^[g^[h^[k`. The keyboard was working just fine in the Desktop Environment (DE) and in the terminal but I don't know what's the issue now.

By the way my keyboard is a wireless keyboard, but I don't think this is the issue here.

#### UPDATE

I have tested the keyboard on a Toshiba laptop running Ubuntu and it works and i checked on another Lenovo laptop running Manjaro Linux and it also works fine. So **the problem is not with the keyboard it self**

#### UPDATE 2

I checked the locales to see if something was wrong, it was set to en_GB UTF-8 and i changed it to en_US UTF-8, the issue remains the same.

#### UPDATE 3

I have just formatted the SD card and now installing Archlinux-ARM to try my luck with another OS.

#### UPDATE 4

After installing Archlinux-ARM, everything is working as it should, the keyboard is perfectly fine, so the problem was with the OS it self. I will never know what the issue was nor try to find out, but I will leave this post for other people, if was decided that the post OS useless please feel free to take down.

---

Thank you for thinking or trying to help everyone, and good luck!

Comment: What output do you get when you type the characters with Ctrl?

Comment: `^[a` looks like Alt or Esc being pressed. If the problem persists even with a reinstall, I'd try another keyboard.

Comment: @kba its not a button being pressed because it works perfectly on two different laptops with two different OS, so the problem is with the OS it self wich is by the way, Rasbian, also, now that i installed archlinux, everything is working as it should, so it means that the problem was with the Rasbian OS